# If pivot table/range is added to Data Model, how to get the the source of pivot table in C#?

Tags: c#

For example, if the source is an Excel table I use pivotTableObj.SourceData
I want to refresh the Pivot table using the C# code.
pivotTableObj.SourceData doesn't work if table/range is not added to Excel Data Model
I am using checkbox from Insert>>Pivot Table dialog box - "Add this data to data model" to add Excel table to Data model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (pivotTable.PivotCache().OLAP == true)
{
    ModelTables modelTable;
    modelTable = MyWorkbook.Model.ModelTables;
    foreach(ModelTable modelTable in modelTables)
    {    
         //my purpose was to refresh the pivot table
         //printing just a name for instance
         System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(modelTable.Name);
    }
}
```